# Why I can't display some site with TWebBrowser

Tags: firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio, twebbrowser

I use Delphi Rio (Windows Desktop App) and need to display in a TWebBrowser some webpages.
I ran into a problem with this WooCommerce site, https://merletdance.com/eshop.
When I ask for this one, I can't pass the cookies dialog. I understand it's in relation with JScript and/or JQuery, but is there a way to bypass or better (some parameters of TwebBrowser) ?

[Edit] Works with Delphi 11 (Alexandria) using Edge

Comment: I it likely an issue with the website that is no more compatible with the outdated and deprecated Internet Explorer (TWebBrowser is based on IE).

Comment: Yes, I was suspected this. I am attempting to migrate my app to D11 to avoid this, but I have some errors and webbrowser still not working !! Suspecting cache

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, even if for my users with heterogeneous park it's not a cure-all: [Embarcadero's documentation on `TWebBrowser`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.WebBrowser.TWebBrowser) hints to edit the registry:

> ### Supporting JavaScript Integration on Windows Platform
>
> On Windows target platforms (WIN32 and WIN64), `TWebBrowser` may incorrectly display some Web pages if a Web site uses JavaScript dialog boxes, panels, and other elements for various purposes.
>
> To work around this issue, your application should display Web pages in the IE11 edge mode using the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION feature of Internet Explorer.
>
> 1. Open the Registry Editor.
> 2. Open the following key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`
> 3. On the **Edit** menu, point to **New**, and then click `DWORD (32-bit) Value`.
> 4. Set the name of this new entry to your executable file name, such as `MyApps.exe`.
> 5. Select the newly created entry, and on the **Edit** menu, click **Modify**.
> 6. In the **Edit** dialog box that opens, do the following:
>
>    - In the **Value data** text box, enter `11011`
>    - Under **Base**, select **Decimal**
>    - Click **OK** to save your changes
>
> You can also cause your application to make the above described changes when the application starts. For example, in your project, the `FormCreate` event handler can call the following `TForm1.SetPermissions` method:
>
> ```pascal
> procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
> begin
> {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
>   SetPermissions;
> {$ENDIF}
> end;
>
> {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
> procedure TForm1.SetPermissions;
>
> const
>   cHomePath = 'SOFTWARE';
>   cFeatureBrowserEmulation =
>     'Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION\';
>   cIE11 = 11001;
>
> var
>   Reg: TRegIniFile;
>   sKey: string;
> begin
>
>   sKey := ExtractFileName(ParamStr(0));
>   Reg := TRegIniFile.Create(cHomePath);
>   try
>     if Reg.OpenKey(cFeatureBrowserEmulation, True) and
>       not(TRegistry(Reg).KeyExists(sKey) and (TRegistry(Reg).ReadInteger(sKey)
>       = cIE11)) then
>       TRegistry(Reg).WriteInteger(sKey, cIE11);
>   finally
>     Reg.Free;
>   end;
>
> end;
> {$ENDIF}
> ```
>
> **Note**: You should make these appropriate changes to the registry before starting the application. After you start your application for the first time, close it, and then start again.